# How to mute and stop autoplay using Twitch API

Tags: javascript, html, api, attributes, twitch

I'm currently trying to create an application that lets you view the top clips from **Twitch.tv** (the popular streaming website) using the [Twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/clips-discovery) for a specific game, which has worked successfully.

However **I can't seem to find where to place the attributes** in the element to have the clips **autoplay disabled and muted**, so that when the application loads, my ears don't blow!

If you visit this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Kastel/pen/LzOVoL), you'll soon see what I'm facing; a collection of clips being triggered to play which mixes all the audio together.

This is the HTML where the videos are placed:

```
<div id="clips-display"></div>
```

And this is the JavaScript in the codepen which appends the video in this divider (is triggered after all videos load from the API):

```
var clipsDisplay = document.getElementById('clips-display'),
    clipList = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

clipList.clips.forEach(function(clip, index, array) {
    clipItem = document.createElement('div');
    clipItem.innerHTML = clip.embed_html;
    clipsDisplay.appendChild(clipItem);
});
```